# So why should we use POST instead of GET for posting data?

Tags: http, post

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How should I choose between GET and POST methods in HTML forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110933/how-should-i-choose-between-get-and-post-methods-in-html-forms)
>   [When do you use POST and when do you use GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585/when-do-you-use-post-and-when-do-you-use-get)

Obviously, you should. But apart from doing so to fulfil the HTTP protocol, are there any reasons to do so? Less overhead? Some kind of security thing?

Comment: Will someone please link to the purported dup?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

because GET must not alter the state of the server by definition.

see [RFC2616 9.1.1 Safe Methods](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html):

> 9.1.1 Safe Methods
>
> Implementors should be aware that the
>   software represents the user in their
>   interactions over the Internet, and
>   should be careful to allow the user to
>   be aware of any actions they might
>   take which may have an unexpected
>   significance to themselves or others.
>
> In particular, the convention has been
>   established that the GET and HEAD
>   methods SHOULD NOT have the
>   significance of taking an action other
>   than retrieval. These methods ought to
>   be considered "safe". This allows user
>   agents to represent other methods,
>   such as POST, PUT and DELETE, in a
>   special way, so that the user is made
>   aware of the fact that a possibly
>   unsafe action is being requested.

If you use GET to alter the state of the server then a search engine bot or some link prefetching extension in a web browser can wreak havoc on your site and (for example) [delete all user data just by following links to your site](http://37signals.com/svn/archives2/google_web_accelerator_hey_not_so_fast_an_alert_for_web_app_designers.php).

Comment: idempotent is the word you're looking for - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence

Comment: not really, no.  Indempotent means that repeating the same request does not change the result.  PUT and DELETE shoult also be idempotent (but are not safe)

Answer (score 11):

There is a nice paper by the W3C about this: *[URIs, Addressability, and the use of HTTP GET and POST](http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/whenToUseGet.html).*

> **1.3 Quick Checklist for Choosing HTTP GET or POST**
>
> - Use GET if:
>
>   - The interaction is more like a question (i.e., it is a safe operation such as a query, read operation, or lookup).
> - Use POST if:
>
>   - The interaction is more like an order, or
>   - The interaction changes the state of the resource in a way that the user would perceive (e.g., a subscription to a service), or
>   - The user be held accountable for the results of the interaction

Answer (score 7):

Because, if you use GET to alter state, [Google can delete your stuff](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/01/21/asp.net-mvc-tip-46-ndash-donrsquot-use-delete-links-because.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

[When do you use POST and when do you use GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585/when-do-you-use-post-and-when-do-you-use-get)

[How should I choose between GET and POST methods in HTML forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110933/how-should-i-choose-between-get-and-post-methods-in-html-forms)

Answer (score 2):

If you accept GETs to perform write operations then a malicious hacker could inject somewhere links to perform an unauthorized operation. Your user clicks on a link - and something is deleted from a database. Or maybe some amount of money is transferred away from the user's account if he's still logged in to their online banking.

http://superbank.com/TransferMoney?amount=1000&recipient=2342524

Send a malicious email with an embedded image referencing this link, and as soon as the document is opened, something funny has happened behind the scenes.

Comment: While this is correct, it wouldn't be much more difficult for a half-competent hacker to trick you into performing a malicious POST request instead.

Comment: But this would be a trick, which can be countered, while image-get is perfectly legal operation

Comment: @ymv: Yes, but you accepting a GET command over a link to update your stuff would be foolish.

Comment: @LukeH How a user can be tricked to perform a malicious POST request? Please give an example.

Answer (score 0):

GET is limited by the length of URL the browser/server can handle.  This used to be as short as 256 characters.

Comment: There is no such limit in HTTP spec. In practice, limits are higher than 256 characters.

Comment: 2000 chars should be regarded as the current practical limit. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-an-url

Comment: "Used to be".  I looked at POST vs GET back in 1997 and the reason I give here was what I found then.

Answer (score 0):

There is atleast one situation where you want a GET to change data on the server. That is when a GET returns data, and you need to record which data was given to a user and when it was given.

If you use complex data types then it must be in a POST it cannot be in a GET. For example testing a WCF web service in a browser can only be done when the contract uses simple data types.

Using GET and POST where it is expected helps to keep your program understandable.

Answer (score -5):

When you use POST, you can see the information being "posted" in the address-bar of the web browser. This is [apparently] not the case when you use the GET method.

This article was somewhere on http://www.w3schools.com/ Once I've found the exact page it was on, I'll repost. :-)

Comment: Wrong way around surely!

Comment: Sorry guys, what the HELL was I thinking!? I know it's the other way around, but I ...Ah... I need to get some sleep