# How To trigger a php query using a link

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have a page, in where by i can want to collect and store the amount of page views, i have a php query that stores my page views onclick of a button,

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    mysql_select_db($database_epl, $epl);
    $query_lin = sprintf("SELECT * FROM topic WHERE id = %s ORDER BY `Date` DESC", GetSQLValueString($colname_lin, "int"));
    $topicId = $_GET['id']; // you need to change 'id' to the name of your ID-parameter in the URL
    $viewsIncrementQuery = "UPDATE `topic` SET `Views` = `Views` + 1 WHERE `id` = " . $topicId;
    $incremented = mysql_query($viewsIncrementQuery, $epl) or die(mysql_error());
    // run/execute mysql query
```

but now i want to be able to call that query using links, (on click of a link)

How can i go about this

Comment: First of all, format your post, it's hard to read. What have you tried and what did not work?

Comment: If you are wanting to stay on the same page you will need to look into using ajax

Comment: Without reloading the page ? use AJAX !

Comment: Send parameters via `_GET`

Comment: i dont intend to stay on the page, i just want to make sure that onlick of that link, the query be excuted,

Answer (score 2):

You can add a onclick event to the link and have it set a form's action attribute and then trigger a submit

html

```
<form method="post" id="myForm">
   <input type="text" name="id" />
   <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<a href="/somePhpScript.php" onclick="submitForm(this)">Click to submit</a>
```

Javascript

```
function submitForm(element){
    var action = element.href;
    var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
    form.action = action;
    form.submit();
}
```

Your data would then be in the `$_POST` global array, if you want it in the `$_GET` global then just change the `method` attribute to `get`

Comment: i think your solution is more of what i was looking for, because my query already carries a post action, thanks, ill try it and get back

Answer (score 0):

You need to call this page with an ajax query, [like this in JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). With this, you'll be able to transmit parameters as GET or POST, and receive them in your page, where you will do your update query.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a parameter with your link:

```
http://example.com/yourpage.php?send=123
```

in yourpage.php

```
var_dump($_GET['send']);
```

returns

```
string(3) => 123
```

EDIT:

in your html output introduce a parameter for your link:

```
 <a href="http://example.com/yourpage.php?updateview=1">link</a>
```

in yourpage.php

```
 if($_GET['updateview'] == 1)
 {
      //your sql query etc. from the question.
 }
```

Comment: can u please apply that to the snippet i gave

Comment: i don't know your link, and i don't know the variable you want to send. but i can write some suggestions.

Comment: Don't use GET-parameters for update actions in the database. He should use a POST-action in his case.

Comment: @Thijs how do you send a POST header with http in a link?

Comment: @RaphaelMüller He should use AJAX.

Comment: @Thijs so you say if you use some rewrite rules on your server like: `example.com/api/save` and pass the `save` as action variable (`$_GET['action']`) to your php script, you can't do that, you have to use ajax and post?

Comment: this is my link       <a href="index.php"   data-ajax="false" data-icon="home"  data-transition="slidedown">Home</a>

Comment: @RaphaelMüller, I think every action that change something to the database should be using a POST-request. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254132/so-why-should-we-use-post-instead-of-get-for-posting-data). If he doesn't want to use AJAX, he could use a form.

Comment: @Thijs I agree with you if you have a REST api or somthing similar, then you have to use GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, MERGE etc. But if you only want to pass some value (no formdata) while clicking a link, you can only use GET without the use of javascript. With this way it's also safe for search machines, of course it's not SEO friendly.

Comment: @RaphaelMüller Forget the JavaScript and AJAX, why not using a form?

Comment: @Thijs because the question of this thread was to use a link ;)