# Action passing null instead of string in asp.net mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am absolutely stuck on this, I have created an action to add a new Identity Role to my database using the Identity Framework. Unfortunately whenever it is executed, it returns that it has failed and after I inserted a breakpoint, I established that I am passing null as the value for `newRole` and not superadmin as would be expected.

The below is the URL I am using, exactly as I am using it:

`https://localhost:44344/account/addrole/superadmin`

And this is the corresponding action:

```
[Authorize(Roles = RoleNames.CanAddUsers)]
public ActionResult AddRole(string newRole)
{
    var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext());
    var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);
    var result = roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole(newRole));

    return result.Succeeded 
        ? Content(newRole + " added to database.") 
        : Content("Failed to add " + newRole + ".");
}
```

Now I have checked and double checked that the user I am logged in as whilst testing this has the role CanAddUsers and I am not being redirected to login but simply receiving `Failed to add  .`

To confirm, the following is my route and I cannot find anything else suggesting my code may be routed in a different manner.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

I am sure at this point it is probably an incredibly obvious mistake but I cannot find it!

- asp.net identity version: 2.2.1
- asp.net mvc version: 5.2.3
- entity framework 6.3.1

Comment: instead of addrole/superadmin maybe should be addrole?newRole=superadmin or create an view and do the post because it is a "get" call

Comment: You shouldn't be using a GET for creating/modifying data. If you must, add [HttpGet("{newRole}")] to your action

Comment: Or else just replace `newRole` with `id` in your controller action.

Comment: `addrole?newRole=superadmin` worked perfectly and then that lead me to understand why I could not make it work... which is exactly what Rafalon said! Thank you all!

Comment: @Stu as Mardoxx pointed out you should really be performing a POST and not a GET

Comment: @Mardoxx can I ask why that should be POST when the action is only actionable by an authorised user? Is this simply down to standard practice or is their a practical difference also.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1254147/3515174 I mean sure chances of someone targeting you are very slim but still it's usually best to follow standards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the MapRoute only, then you should know that the name of the optional parameter (`id` in your case) will be used.

Then you should either rename your Action's parameter to `id`, or explicitly say that you use the `newRole` variable by writing `addrole?newRole=superadmin`.

Or else, as others pointed out, you may prefer to use POST instead of GET for this.