# jQuery post not passing parameters

Tags: php, jquery

I have a problem with posting variable to *php* script and getting result back without refreshing page. *php* script `koord.php` is tested and it's working fine.

#### This is my js code (`adresa`, `mjest`o and `coords` are text input boxes):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#coord_click').click(function () {
        provjera();
    });
});

function provjera() {

    var adresa = $('#adresa').val();
    var mjesto = $('#mjesto').val();
    var puna_adresa = adresa + " " + mjesto;

    $.post("koord.php", { puna_adresa: puna_adresa },function (result) {
        $('#coords').val(result);
    });
}
```

### koord.php:

```
$puna_adresa = $_GET['puna_adresa']; 

function getCoordinates($address){ 
    $address = str_replace(" ", "+", $address); 
    $url = "maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/…"; 
    $response = file_get_contents($url); 
    $json = json_decode($response,TRUE); 

    return ($json['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'].",".$json['results'][0]['geo‌​metry']['location']['lng']); 
} 

echo getCoordinates($puna_adresa);
```

Complete source code is here: http://pastebin.com/u/bradetic

Thank you!

Comment: can you show the code of `koord.php`?

Comment: $puna_adresa=$_GET['puna_adresa'];
function getCoordinates($address){
$address = str_replace(" ", "+", $address); 
$url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=$address";
$response = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($response,TRUE);
return ($json['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'].",".$json['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']);
}
echo getCoordinates($puna_adresa);

Comment: check my answer, next time add the code to the question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jquery POST is not the problem.

Your are doing `$.post(...)` which means that you need to get the parameter in `koord.php` via `$_POST`, and you are using `$_GET`, you see the problem right?

#### Solution

Change `$_GET['puna_adresa'];` to `$_POST['puna_adresa'];`

**or**

change `$.post(...)` for `$.get(...)` in your client side.

#### You know the difference between `POST` and `GET` right?

- [When do you use POST and when do you use GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585/when-do-you-use-post-and-when-do-you-use-get)
- [How should I choose between GET and POST methods in HTML forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110933/how-should-i-choose-between-get-and-post-methods-in-html-forms)

Comment: @user2986503: Don't forget to mark a response as the answer to the question. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You seriously need to use Jquery AJAX, here's an example:

```
<script>

function your_function()
{

// collect data like this
var formData = jQuery("#your_form_id").serializeArray();

jQuery.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url:"your_php_page.php",  
    data:formData,
    dataType:'json',

    beforeSend: function()
    {
    },
    success: function(resp)
    {  

        alert(resp);

    }, 
    complete: function()
    {
    },
    error: function(e)
    {  
        alert('Error: ' + e); 
    }  
}); 

}

</script>
```

And you PHP script should go like this:

```
$puna_adresa=$_POST['puna_adresa']; 

function getCoordinates($address){ 
$address = str_replace(" ", "+", $address); 
$url = "maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/…;; 
$response = file_get_contents($url); 
return $response;
} 

$response = getCoordinates($puna_adresa);

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Can I use instead jQuery("#your_form_id") jquery("#adresa,#mjesto") because i have multiple input fields an I need just these two.

Comment: Is the same thing... there is no problem with the client side code

Comment: And instead alert(resp) can I put this $('#coords').val(resp) to show the results in input field? I haven't tried yet this because i'm at work now.

Comment: oops, my answer is perfect for this sort of problem but someone just vote down my answer, you are genius pal, i am still shocked :s

Comment: yes of coarse, your script will return you everything in resp array, you can easily put this array in a loop and alert it's contents.

Comment: @Ali: I downvoted the answer before because there was no problem with the ajax request, the problem was (as you pointed now) with getting the `puna_adresa` param via `$_GET`. Now is ok, downvote deleted ;)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
     $.post("koord.php", { puna_adresa: adresa, mjesto: mjesto }, function (result) {
        $('#coords').val(result);
    });
```

Another way:

```
    $.post("koord.php", $( "#testform" ).serialize(), function (result) {
        $('#coords').val(result);
    });
```

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: why this would change anything?

Answer (score 0):

you May try this

```
$.post( "koord.php", $( "#testform" ).serialize() );
```