# Ajax Call Parameter is not passing into PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
    function hashValue(ID){
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/getHashvalue.php",
                    data: {ID:ID},
                    success: function(res) {
                        alert(res);
                    }
                });
            }
```

The above jQuery Ajax call is passing ID as the Parameter successfully.

But the PHP code is not able to receive the ID sent by Ajax.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['ID']))
{
    $hashid = $_POST['ID'];
}
$hash = hash('sha1', $hashid);
print_r($hash);
exit;
?>
```

Error is as follows

```
( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: hashid in G:\wamp\www\wp-content\themes\theme1\getHashvalue.php on line 6
```

Comment: `print_r($_POST);` *before* and *outside* the `if` statement. Does it contain `ID`?

Comment: @AmalMurali - If it did, would `isset($_POST['ID'])` fail ?

Comment: try with isset($_REQUEST['ID']) instead

Comment: Why not just `$_GET['ID']`, as thats where it is

Comment: $_POST replaced by $_GET solved my problem

Comment: @adeneo: No, it would not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default HTTP method of `jQuery.ajax` is a GET request, not a POST request.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

So you need to be checking `$_GET['ID']`, not `$_POST`.

Comment: This solved my problem. Will accept it as answer soon.

POST is secured than GET, is it possible to change the Default GET to POST request?

Comment: Yup. Or change the client side to add `type: "POST"` to the ajax() parameters (or use jQuery's [post() shorthand](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).)

Comment: Yes. In your `jQuery.ajax` call, add the option `type: 'POST'`, as described in the docs I linked.

Comment: @harishannam Could you expand on "POST is secured than GET"? I'd not say either method was more secure in an Ajax call, if that's what you're meaning...

Comment: A POST request doesn't send the data as a querystring, but it's still pretty accessible with something like Fiddler etc.

Comment: @MattGibson I read in w3schools stating that GET method is not much secure as it stores data in browser. So I thought same applies for Ajax calls.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "secure". Anything that's in the middle could easily sniff either of them unless they're secured by using an https connection, say. Generally, the way to choose between them has more to do with what the request is *for* than security. Does this request read or change an object, will it be helpful to bookmark/pass to others, etc. etc. [This question has some answers that give some idea of the choices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110933/how-should-i-choose-between-get-and-post-methods-in-html-forms).