# Why is file upload not supported by a GET request?

Tags: http, http-post, http-get

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/110939/1779091) suggests that GET request does not support file uploads. Why is this?

So if the endpoint needs to have a file upload, then irrespective of whether it is a read endpoint or write endpoint, we should make it a POST?

Answer (score 0):

`GET` requests send data directly as the part of URL - like `http://someapi.net/api?key=API_KEY`. There are limits in some browsers and web servers that how big an URL can be - and posting a whole file as the part of URL is fairly weird. Yes, you should use `POST`.

Comment: In a GET request, why can't we not upload the file like how we do in POST request via the message body (instead of the url parameter as you mentioned)?